# grep or sed or awk + match WORD

Tags: grep

I do the following in order to get all WORD in file but not in lines that start with "//"

```
  grep -v "//"  file | grep WORD
```

Can I get some other elegant suggestion to find all occurrences of `WORD` in the file except lines that begin with `//`?

Remark:  "//" does not necessarily exist at the beginning  of the line; there could be some spaces before "//".

For example

```
 // WORD
 AA WORD
         // ss WORD
```

Comment: your approach drops this line:

WORD aa; // the word aa

Comment: Also: your `grep WORD` will also match any instances of 'SWORDS' on a line. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -v "//"  file | grep WORD
```

This will also exclude any lines with "//" after WORD, such as:

> WORD // This line here

A better approach with GNU Grep would be:

```
 grep -v '^[[:space:]]*//' file | grep 'WORD'
```

...which would first filter out any lines beginning with zero-or-more spaces and a comment string.

Trying to put these two conditions into a single regular expression is probably not more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/^[ \t]*\/\// && /WORD/{m=gsub("WORD","");total+=m}END{print total}' file
```

Comment: how to count the WORD with your example (if I want to know how many WORD i Have in file)

Comment: @lidia: How to *count* the number of WORDs in a file is a separate question. You should either update your question or ask a new one.